# randomly select the data from the dictionary form

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
data= np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [10,3,10,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
        [10,10,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,11,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]], dtype='float')

my_groups = ['Group_A', 'Group_B', 'Group_C']
my_values = [7, 10, 11]
my_data ={}
for x, y in zip(my_groups, my_values):
    my_data[x] = np.where(data==y)
print my_data

#{'Group_C': (array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([ 8, 10,  8,  9, 10,  8,  9, 10,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int64)), 'Group_B': (array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64), array([10,  0,  2,  0,  1,  7,  6], dtype=int64)), 'Group_A': (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int64), array([5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4], dtype=int64))}
```

Now, I want to randomly select three index positions for each group and put them into dictionary form:

```
samples = {}
for x,y in zip(my_groups,my_data):
    for i in np.random.choice(len(my_data), 3, replace=True):
        samples[x] = np.array(my_data[x][i], dtype=np.int64)

print samples
```

Looking for good ideas. I could not make the samples working.

EDIT: This is for consistency check:

```
import numpy as np
data= np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [10,3,10,4,7,7,7,8,300,12,11],  
        [300,10,100,5,7,7,7,9,200,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,200,7,100,11,11,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]], dtype='float')

my_groups = ['Group_A', 'Group_B', 'Group_C']
my_values = [100, 200, 300]
my_data ={}
for x,y in zip(my_groups, my_values):
    my_data[x] = np.where(data==y)
print my_data

samples = {}
for x,y in my_data.iteritems():
    idx_choice = np.random.choice(len(y[0]),2, replace=False)
    samples[x] = (y[0][idx_choice],y[1][idx_choice])
print samples

samples = {}
for x, y in my_data.iteritems():
    samples[x] = [(y[0][i],y[1][i]) for i in np.random.choice(len(y[0]),2,replace=False)]
print samples
```

Comment: i could not make samples working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to randomly select three pairs of indexes (as returned by `np.where`) for each group you have determined.

This can be easily done e.g. via a list comprehension.

Consider this

```
 samples = {}
 for x,y in my_data.iteritems():
     samples[x] = [(y[0][i],y[1][i]) for i in np.random.choice(len(y[0]),3)]
```

output

```
 samples
 {'Group_A': [(2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 6)],
  'Group_B': [(3, 7), (3, 7), (2, 0)],
  'Group_C': [(2, 10), (2, 8), (2, 10)]}
```

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you might want an output closer to what returned by `np.where`. In that case you can do

```
samples = {}
for x,y in my_data.iteritems():
    idx_choice = np.random.choice(len(y[0]),3)
    samples[x] = (y[0][idx_choice],y[1][idx_choice])
```

which gives

```
samples
{'Group_A': (array([0, 3, 3]), array([7, 4, 5])),
'Group_B': (array([1, 1, 2]), array([2, 2, 1])),
'Group_C': (array([2, 3, 2]), array([9, 8, 9]))}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i would prefer to getting the index values in the way it is returned by np.where function

Comment: @neha, answer has been changed for that.

Comment: the obtained positions in case of samples are not consistent with the positions of original data

Comment: for me both the x and y position of an element should not be changed

Comment: in your answer the x,y positions with in the element position seems to be randomly reversing..

Comment: @neha, As in matrix notation, the first index is always the row index, while the second is the column index (and this is consistent with the output). In other word, the first element is the row, the second element is the column. Moreover, x and y is the pair of dict key and element. Wish to double check the results.

Comment: here i mean x, y as the row and column of an element

Comment: @neha. Ok. Again, you have row index first and column index as second. They both start from zero. I checked your second code and things look ok.